# Check if an item exists in MDX named set

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I want to create a named set for two football teams. I'm not exactly sure what the syntax is, but what I have thus far is:

```
EXISTS(
    [Team].[Team], 
    {[Team].[Team].&[BAL], [Team].[Team].&[DEN]}
)
```

In other words, I want to create a Named set if the team is named "BAL" or "DEN". What would be the proper way to write this expresion?

---

The following query syntax works for me, but I'd like to translate this into "creating a named set" in BIDS:

```
WITH SET[FavoriteTeams] AS{
   [Team].[Team].&[DEN],
   [Team].[Team].&[BAL]
} 
SELECT
   [Measures].[Net Wins] on 0,
   [FavoriteTeams] on 1
FROM [NFL]
```

---

It seems perhaps it is as simple as just typing that in manually to the expression?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are an important concept in MDX. A set is a collection of members from the same dimension and hierarchy. The hierarchy can be an attribute hierarchy or a user-defined hierarchy.

```
set = {membre1,member 2 ..}
```

the simpler the set expression the better it is.

So you should use the second expression

```
{
   [Team].[Team].&[DEN],
   [Team].[Team].&[BAL]
}
```

In your case no need to use the exists function since the members are defined.
we use exists in some setuations like we want to get all the cities of a specific region.

```
 EXISTS([City].[City], [region].[region].[Region].&[1])
```

Visit : [Microsoft.doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-named-sets-creating-session-scoped-named-sets?view=asallproducts-allversions)